# Using Node to Run Compound repo

Tags: ethereum, yarnpkg

I'm following the instructions found here:
https://github.com/compound-finance/compound-protocol

I've ran:

git clone https://github.com/compound-finance/compound-protocol

cd compound-protocol

yarn install --lock-file

yarn test

yarn run v1.22.11

$ ./script/test

Unknown option: p

Unknown option: p

Type shasum -h for help

Type shasum -h for help

error Command failed with exit code 1.

info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

Why do I keep getting this error with unknown option p

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Node.js version 12. NVM is a great tool to quickly switch between versions of Node on the command line. https://nvm.sh